# Creating new cluster table on file group

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, ssms

I keep getting an error message incorrect syntax near `ON`. Can someone please help me figuring out why?

```
CREATE TABLE [CustomerService.Contacts]

(

        --A

        ContactID int IDENTITY(1,1),

        CONSTRAINT PK_ContactID PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED (ContactID),

        --B

        CustomerID int not null,

        CONSTRAINT FK_CustomerID FOREIGN KEY (CustomerID)

        REFERENCES Sales.Customer (CustomerID),

        --C

        RepID int not null,

        CONSTRAINT FK_RepID FOREIGN KEY (RepID)

        REFERENCES CustomerService.Reps (RepID),

        --D

        ContactDateTime date not null,

        --E

        ContactMethod varchar(5) DEFAULT 'Other' not null,

        CHECK (ContactMethod IN ('Email', 'Phone', 'Chat', 'Other')),

        --F

        ContactPhone varchar(14) null,

        --G

        ContactEmail varchar(50) null,

        --H

        ContactDetail varchar(MAX) not null,

ON  AD_CustomerService;

GO

ALTER TABLE CustomerService.Contacts

REBUILD PARTITION = ALL WITH (DATA_COMPRESSION = PAGE);

GO
```

Comment: This doesn't work on MySQL because this looks like MSSQL. What are you really using?

Comment: Microsoft SQL server management

Comment: Please correct the tag accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

You never closed the parenthesis you opened after the first line:

```
CREATE TABLE [CustomerService.Contacts]

(
```

so you are probably missing a close parenthesis before the `ON` keyword:

```
...
        ContactDetail varchar(MAX) not null,

        )  -- <---this was missing

ON  AD_CustomerService;

GO

ALTER TABLE CustomerService.Contacts

REBUILD PARTITION = ALL WITH (DATA_COMPRESSION = PAGE);

GO
```